# How to represent the SQL value NULL in ActiveRecord#create calls?

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Since `seeds.rb` is in Ruby, I'm guessing that if I want the effect of

```
insert into foo values (hoo: "ioo", koo: null);
```

I should do something like

```
Foo.create(hoo: "ioo", koo: nil)
```

Does the Ruby value `nil` map to the SQL value `null` in this case?  I'm aware that

```
Foo.create(hoo: "ioo")
```

will create a row with `koo` of `NULL`, but the lines of my `seeds.rb` in this case are strings concatenated together in a quick-n-dirty SQL query, so simply skipping columns with null values might require even more mental effort than getting the node module `better-sqlite3` to stop spitting out version mismatch messages.  I suppose I could rake these seeds and test out my `nil`->`NULL` hypothesis instead of asking here, but I'm new enough to rails that I'm paranoid about breaking things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all of the SQL gems that I'm aware of translate Ruby `nil` into SQL `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Foo.create(hoo: "ioo", koo: nil)` will set the `koo` column to NULL.

You can't really break anything by running `seeds.rb` and see what gets created. If it's not what you wanted, delete it and try again!